# Create multiple kubernetes namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on the best way to create 200 namespaces within a cluster.
Ideally a simple bash loop to create `kubectl create namespaces` would be good.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to keep track of this in a Git repo?

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically create a YAML file using any programming language you are most comfortable with (bash or python), consisting of a list of k8s namespaces with the following format:

```
$ cat namespaces-list.yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Namespace
  metadata:
  name: namespace-list1
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Namespace
  metadata:
  name: namespace-list2
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Namespace
  metadata:
  name: namespace-list3
```

Then execute the following command to create them all in one shot! `kubectl apply -f namespaces-list.yaml`

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

I eventually came up with something as simple this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  for i in $(seq 100); do
    kubectl create namespace test-${i}
         
done
```